# Irregular response pattern from WebMethod in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webmethod

The old ASP.NET WebForms project is getting migrated to ASP.NET MVC. The ASP.NET MVC web application contains many ASPX pages. The WebMethods are kept in the code behind file of the ASPX page. AJAX call is made to the WebMethod to get the response using jQuery.

For the initial migration, we want to keep the old ASP.NET WebForms and want to add new pages in MVC(Razor pages). Gradually the old WebForms will be converted to MVC.

Below is an example of the WebMethod used:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string GetMenu()
{
  return Utility.CreateMenu();
}
```

The jQuery AJAX call is done like follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'default.aspx/GetMenu',
    type: 'GET',
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {           
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

We are getting a strange behavior for the WebMethod response. The response is sometimes is returned as a JSON object and sometimes a string wrapped with the "d" object.

String wrapped with "d" example:

```
{"d":"[{\"SubItems\":null,\"MenuState\":\"2\",\"Description\":\"Create issue\",\"Url\":\"default.aspx?id=1234\"}]"}
```

JSON response example:

```
{SubItems: null, MenuState: "2", Description: "Create issue", Url: "default.aspx?id=1234"}
```

Previously, when the ASP.NET MVC was not added it was returning the response as string wrapped with in the "d" object.

**Notes**

- The WebMethod response pattern is random. Sometimes it is returning string wrapped within "d" and sometimes pure JSON.
- The AJAX calls to the MVC Action is returning JSON response always.
- Initially in MVC the WebMethod was not working as the path was giving 404 URL. We have added ignore route in RouteConfig. `routes.IgnoreRoute("{aspxpage}.aspx/{*webmethod}");`
- The WebMethod is returning the string which is serialized like: `new
  JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);`
- After getting AJAX response, the string is parsed to get the JSON
  object which is failing sometimes.  `var obj = JSON.parse(response.d);`

Is there any way to force the WebMethod to return the string wrapped with the "d" object? Or any other way how to handle this issue?

Comment: Might be a caching issue, try to set ajax option `cache` to `false` and / or add some sort of timestamp parameter to the ajax call to rule out caching issues.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Perhaps you should check logic of `Utility.CreateMenu`.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy , I tried disabling cache(cache: false) for AJAX request but didn't work.

Comment: @Bob, the Utility.CreateMenu() method is returning a serialized list of items. Like: return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(List<MenutItems>);

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but the `IgnoreRoute` you have setup `{aspxpage}.aspx/{*webmethod}` will ignore **all** `.aspx` pages because the last parameter is a catch-all (meaning it is optional). If you only want it to ignore web methods and not ASP.NET pages, it should be like `{aspxpage}.aspx/{webmethod}`.